# Error running server django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model-view-controller

I have moved my django project to another new machine driven by virtualBox. I have installed everything I need to run my project. **Python 3.6 and django 1.9**

Unfortunately, when I try to run it I got an error saying something that is not possible to find all project required paths.

my path project is:
[image]

path: C:\users\Dev\Documents\GitHub\Python\django\local_sites

```
--local_sites
--manage.py
----local_sites
------forms
------models
------urls
------etc.
```

When, I run in the local_sites where is located the manage.py the runserver I got the error below:

[image]

I when thru the file urls.py to check out the line 17 , but I dont understand really how to figure it out

[image]

I appreciate the help you can give me.

thanks so much

Comment: Are you using `django2.0` or a earlier version like 1.11 or 1.8 ?

Comment: added in the post!! @ChihebNexus

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.9 uses `url` instead of `path`.  See your other `urlpatterns`, for example.

`from django.conf.urls import url`

And use:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', local_views.home, name="home")
]
```

see docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/